# Stop services gracefully on shutdown (increase timer)

Tags: server, 20.04, shutdown

I have a service with a long stop procedure (up to 3-5 Minutes sometimes)

The service is handling a database and harddrives. Upon shutdown, ubuntu gives the service a few seconds (i think 90) before killing it. This poses risk of corrupted files.
Is there a way to increase that shutdown timer?

Comment: Have you experimented with `TimeoutStopSec`? It is documented in `man systemd.service`, but you need to dig quite deep. It's around line 300.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is controlled in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. `#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s` is commented out: remove the comment sign and add your custom value.